# sqlite3 select query not returning row with single quote

Tags: sqlite

I have a row in a table with the value of "2005/Mom's Birthday Pie/P9160566_1.JPG".

I am trying to select this row using sqlite3 on Mac 10.13 at the Terminal using the following statement:

```
'select RKMaster.fileName from RKMaster where RKMaster.imagePath = "2005/Mom''s Birthday Pie/P9160566_1.JPG"'
```

But it returns an empty result.  I know the row exists because I can use the application DB Browser for SQLite to filter on the imagePath column using the value "Mom's Birthday Pie/P9160566_1.JPG" (without escaping the ') and I see the row I'm looking for.

What am I doing wrong with my sqlite3 query?

Comment: Does `LIKE` instead of `=` work?

Comment: @CL. No, that doesn't work.. BUT, thanks for the suggestion.. If I use LIKE while also substituting the ' for the wildcard %, it does work!

    `'select RKMaster.fileName from RKMaster where RKMaster.imagePath like "2005/Mom%s Birthday Pie/P9160566_1.JPG"'`

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(imagePath) FROM RKMaster WHERE ...` for this row?

Comment: `'select hex(imagePath) from RKMaster where RKMaster.uuid = "Xuq0SbjJTmOuMN5yFJxHNA"'` (that uuid is another identifier of the row in question) results in `323030352F5265696E612052616E676572205265756E69746564204D6F6D2773204269727468646179205069652F50393136303536365F312E4A5047`

Comment: That looks like a perfectly fine ASCII single quote. But your original search does not mention "Reina Ranger Reunited".

Comment: That's because I was simplifying the actual values for the stack overflow post.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a string, quotes must be doubled to escape them. But that is true only for those quotes that actually delimit the string:

```
'Mom''s'
"Mom""s"
'Mom"s'
"Mom's"
```

(Double quotes are not intended for string values; they should be used for table/column names only, and are accepted by SQLite only for bug-compatibility with MySQL.)

Comment: Ok.  But in my case, I'm delimiting the string with double quotes: ".  If I don't escape the inner single quote in Mom's, then when I press return at the terminal, the command does not execute but continues to await input.  I've tried escaping the ' with a backslash \' but that also does not work.